# How to make a table editable by a form

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to make a website where you can fill in a form. But I want to make it so that the results of the form are collected and put into a table for show on another page. I've researched and played around with html but i can't find a way. I'd prefer it if i could only use at the most of html, php and css. I'm new to web development.

Comment: Where is code, you have tried/played?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need:
1. HTML page with a form to collect the data
2. PHP script/page to get the data from the form and insert it in a database
3. PHP page to retrieve the information from the database and show it to the user

What you need to learn:
1. How to create a form and what the "action" attribute does (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)
2. How to use PHP to insert information in the database (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)
3. How to retrieve and show the information from your database (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

You should really research before coming here for answers - all of this is just the first pages your search comes onto

Comment: I did, but the majority of what popped up was nothing like what i'm trying to do. And thanks for the references

Comment: Just an advice, the official documentation is always the best way to go (like http://php.net), then you have w3c for many things, they are the world wide regulator - extremely authoritative and last but not least (when you get lost in the docs) - the angel, our savior Staaack - Overflow. You'll need nothing else